# Add a property to grouped objects and ungroup

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm using underscore.js to group my objects, now I want to add a property to work as an identifier for that group and then reduce those objects back into its original structure. But not sure how to do it.

The rule is to find who has more than one appointment in that day and add a property to it.

Something we achieved here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bjxgszmw/

with this line of code:

```
var resultt = _.chain(allAppointments)
    .groupBy('appointment_date')
    .mapObject( date => _.groupBy(date, 'email' ) )
```

So from what we have've got which is this:

```
{
  "23July": {
    "john@domain.com": [
      {
        "ap_id": 23,
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@domain.com",
        "appointment_date": "23July",
        "appointment_category": 3,
        "time": "morning"
      },
      {
        "ap_id": 44,
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@domain.com",
        "appointment_date": "23July",
        "appointment_category": 4,
        "time": "afternon"
      }
    ],
    "rose@domain.com": [
      {
        "ap_id": 55,
```

to something simple like this;

```
allAppointments_Filtered: 
      [{
            "ap_id": 23,
            "name": "John",
            "email": "John@domain.com",
            "appointment_date": "23July",
            "appointment_category": 3,
            "time": "morning",
            hasMultipleAppointmentOnDate: "yes"

            },{

           "ap_id": 55,
           "name": "Rose",
           "email": "rose@domain.com",
           "appointment_date": "23July",
           "appointment_category": 4,
           "time": "afternoon"
            hasMultipleAppointmentOnDate: "nope"

            },{

           "ap_id": 44,
           "name": "John",
           "email": "john@domain.com",
           "appointment_date": "23July",
           "appointment_category": 4,
           "time": "afternoon"
            hasMultipleAppointmentOnDate: "yes"

            },{
              ...

      }];
```

Comment: what is the rule for the added propery? please add your try to the question.

Comment: The rule is to find who has more than one appointment in that day and add a property to it. I 'm trying different iteration and it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by a composite key:

```js
// data
const allAppointments = [
 {
        "ap_id": 23,
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@domain.com",
        "appointment_date": "23July",
        "appointment_category": 3,
        "time": "morning"    
   },
      {
        "ap_id": 55,
        "name": "Rose",
        "email": "rose@domain.com",
        "appointment_date": "23July",
        "appointment_category": 4,
        "time": "afternon"        
      },
      {
        "ap_id": 44,
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@domain.com",
        "appointment_date": "23July",
        "appointment_category": 4,
        "time": "afternon"        
      },
      {
        "ap_id": 70,
        "name": "Kate",
        "email": "kate@domain.com",
        "appointment_date": "29July",
        "appointment_category": 4,
        "time": "afternon"        
      }
];

// gets grouping key, which is email + date
const groupKey = i => i.email +'_'+ i.appointment_date;

// store counts for appointments for unique (email + date)
const counts = _.countBy(allAppointments,groupKey);

// checks if appointment has more than one instances on date
const isMulti = i => counts[groupKey(i)] > 1;

// updated appointment with multiple indicator property
const multiProp = i => ({hasMultipleAppointmentOnDate: isMulti(i) ? "yes": "nope"});

// update initial array items with multiple 
const updated = _.map(allAppointments,i => _.extend(i,multiProp(i)));

// see results
console.log(updated);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks man, you and @matei answer at the same time and pretty much with similar solution, matei's one is also wroks fine and does the job however I'm gonna have to pick this one as the chosen answer, as you've broken it down and  and answered more clearly and with more details. (all the way to yes:nope .. :)  ) anyways thanks to both of you guys.

Comment: If you wanted to later keep first instance of the Multis and remove the rest of the multis from the array, would you run similar steps after the update? how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't need to do all those grouping and mappings. All you have to do is a single map and a count based on the current appointment you check:

```js
var allAppointments = [
 {
        "ap_id": 23,
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@domain.com",
        "appointment_date": "23July",
        "appointment_category": 3,
        "time": "morning"    
   },
      {
        "ap_id": 55,
        "name": "Rose",
        "email": "rose@domain.com",
        "appointment_date": "23July",
        "appointment_category": 4,
        "time": "afternon"        
      },
      {
        "ap_id": 44,
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@domain.com",
        "appointment_date": "23July",
        "appointment_category": 4,
        "time": "afternon"        
      },
      {
        "ap_id": 70,
        "name": "Kate",
        "email": "kate@domain.com",
        "appointment_date": "29July",
        "appointment_category": 4,
        "time": "afternon"        
      }
]

var counts = {};
var result = _.mapObject(allAppointments, (appointment) => {
    var key = appointment.email + appointment.appointment_date;
    
    if (!_.has(counts, key)) {
        counts[key] = _.countBy(allAppointments, (app) => 
            appointment.email === app.email && 
            appointment.appointment_date === app.appointment_date
        ).true > 1
    }
    
    appointment.hasMultipleAppointmentOnDate = counts[key];

    return appointment;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```